# when select row the first selectedrow shows blank

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In the viewDidLoad, I called tableview selectRowAtIndexPath at row 0, after that when I click other rows, row 0 shows blank. What's wrong? The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITableView *leftTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 300)];
    leftTableView.dataSource = self;
    leftTableView.delegate = self;
    leftTableView.tag = 0;
    [leftTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [leftTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    });
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableView *rightTableView = (UITableView *)[self viewWithTag:1];
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            self.right = self.left[indexPath.row][@"subchild"];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [rightTableView reloadData];
            });
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the first row to be selected even if you click on other rows? 1 more Question. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you did the code (UITableView *)[self viewWithTag:1]; but in viewDidLoad you gave 0 tag to the tableView. I didn't get that.

Comment: I don't want to keep the first row to be selected if I click on other rows. Just ignore tag, they are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [leftTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
});
```

execute this method after delay.
May this will help you.